# Search people which "choosing" from another app

Tags: windows-8

When selecting a contact, for a new Messaging message for example, you are taken to the People app. However, if you search using the search charm you are taken back to the referring app.

My workaround at the moment is to start in the people app and "send a message" from there, but this seems at ends with how I would think about this task.

Is there a way to text-search from within a "chooser" or is this simply a user experience oversight?